# Cannot send ostringstream variable over socket in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

Could someone please, explain to me why a `string` variable I have derived using `ostringstream` cannot be sent over a socket?

```
std::ostringstream oss1;
std::ostringstream oss2;

int code = 52;

oss1 << "4" << "1" << "0" << "0" << "0" << "0" << 224 + code / 16 << code % 16;
oss2 << "4" << "0" << "0" << "0" << "0" << "0" << 224 + code / 16 << code % 16;

int msg_len3 = oss1.tellp;
int msg_len4 = oss2.tellp;

std::string var1 = oss1.str();
std::string var2 = oss2.str();

comm_send1 = send(sock, var1, msg_len3, 0);
comm_send2 = send(sock, var2, msg_len4, 0);
```

With this code I am getting an error of:

> no suitable conversion function from std::string to const char* exists

Comment: Use `var1.c_str()`

Comment: " why a variable I have derived using ostringstream cannot be send over a socket?"  - because socket libraries don't know anything about C++ std::strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the [`send()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-send) function requires a `const char *` argument, not a `std::string`, which is what `.str()` gives you.

Try this instead:

```
comm_send1 = send(sock, var1.c_str(), msg_len3, 0);
```

The `.c_str()` member function of `std::string` gives you the type you need: a C-style string.

Comment: Additionally, I should say that the error message you're seeing is telling you _exactly_ what the problem is...